# Response.Redirect not changing URL

Tags: vb.net, redirect, asp.net-ajax, ascx

After clicking an element on my webpage, I get the expected behavior from Response.Redirect in the trace, the break point on the expected page gets hit and proceeds to process normally.  However when I'd expect the new page to be loaded, the display in the browser is not changed.  It looks and behaves like the click brought you back to the same page.

I've moved the redirect call out of a try-catch block, and have tried different combinations of true/false as the second parameter with HttpContext...CompleteRequest()

What might prevent a page from being loaded after a call from Response.Redirect and the Page_Load sub completes?

Edit:
The site uses css and javascript to create a hoverable dropdown menu containing self referencing links, see below.  I have tried using Chrome's dev tools to see what the network was processing.  As far as I can tell from reading the Network Tab the click was creating the correct call; status 200, type xhr.  xhr was the only thing that I found odd, but it looks like this is simply a reference to ajax?  This leaves me in the same position.  I am telling the site to redirect to  new url, and I see the network take a request for that url, but the url in the address bar doesn't change; not the displayed page.

```
 $(document).on('click','.navigation', function () {
            loadItems($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('itemName'));
            return false;
        }
        );

var loadItems = function (id, itemName) {
    var editInfor =
        {
            "method": "getChildItems",
            "id": id
        };

    $.ajax
        (
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: $.url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(editInfor),
                success: function (jsonReply) {

                    $("#chkEnabled").attr('checked', jsonReply.enabled)
                    if (jsonReply.method == 'getChildItems') {

                        $("#childrens").html('');
                        var html = '<table>'
                        if (jsonReply.successfull) {
                            $.each(jsonReply.children, function (i, item) {
                                html += '<tr><td><span class="children">' + item.text + '</span></td><td><a class="moveItemUp btn" href="#" id="moveItemUp' + item.id + '">Move Up <i class="icon-circle-arrow-up"></i></a> <a class="moveItemDown btn" href="#" id="moveItemDown' + item.id + '">Move Down <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i></a></td><td><a href="#" class="removeItem btn btn-danger" id="removeItem' + item.id + '">Remove</a></td></tr>'

                            });
                        }
                        html += '</table>'
                        $($.childrens).html(html);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Does the page that you are redirecting to also have code to redirect you back to your original page on load?

Comment: @NoAlias: No, Just double checked

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "/Exmaple.aspx", {

  transition: "pop"

});
```

Comment: This looks like javascript,  How can I use this within logic checking the results from a database?